# Holomorphic Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ $\ne$ const be holomorphic in $D$ $\subset$ $C$ is open and connected. Prove that the image $f(D)$ is open and connected.

Is it sufficient to start the proof with any point, the image $f(D)$ contains all point of some neighborhood?

Comment: Proof of open mapping theorem.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729, so just the same proof as the open mapping theorem? What if in the problem, we replace the word "holomorphic" with the word "continuous", can we guarantee that $f(D)$ is open?